# For which $p$ does $\int_0^1 x^p(x+1)\log x \ dx $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My question is this: for which value of $p$ does this improper integral converge?

$$\int_0^1 x^p(x+1)\log x \ dx $$

I know from a previous exercise that
$$\int_0^1 x^p\log x \ dx $$
converges for $p > -1$.

So for this integral

$$\int_0^1 x^p(x+1)\log x \ dx $$

I found
$$x^p(x+1)\log x = x^{p+1}\log x \ + x^p\log x$$

and
$$x^{p+1}\log x \ + x^p\log x \le 2x^{p+1}\log x$$

and
$$2x^{p+1}\log x \asymp x^{p+1}\log x$$

and I assume from the previous exercise that the integral must converge for $p > -2$ and since the polynomial beats the log with $x$ from $0$ to $1$ for values of $p > -2$.

Is my procedure right?

Comment: Careful: What's the sign of $x^p \log x$ and $x^{p+1} \log x$? Is $x^p$ or $x^{p+1}$ larger?

Comment: I have that $x^p\log x$ is negative and that $x^p$ is bigger so if i multiply by negative it'll become smaller so my inequality is true? but not if $-1<p<1$

Comment: So yes, it's true that $x^p(x+1)\log x \leq 2x^{p+1} \log x$. This shows divergence when the integral of $x^{p+1} \log x$ diverges, but doesn't help with convergence, since it's also true for a function approaching $-\infty$. To show convergence for appropriate $p$,  you have zero as the upper bound but want a function bounding the integrand from below, $g(x) \leq x^p (x+1) \log x \leq 0$ where $g(x)$ is integrable. (As Danny's answer explains, $g(x)=x^p \log x$ is a good bound using your previous exercise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $x\in(0,1)$, $x^{p}\ln x<0$ and $1<x+1<2$, so
$x^{p}\ln x>x^{p}(x+1)\ln x>2x^{p}\ln x$. Therefore, for any $\delta\in(0,1)$,
we have that $\int_{\delta}^{1}x^{p}\ln x\,dx\geq\int_{\delta}^{1}x^{p}(x+1)\ln x\,dx\geq2\int_{\delta}^{1}x^{p}\ln x\,dx$.
(Actually we have strict inequality. However, we do not need this
fact.)

Now, we can show that $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0+}\int_{\delta}^{1}x^{p}\ln x\,dx$
exists iff $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow0+}\int_{\delta}^{1}x^{p}(x+1)\ln x\,dx$
exists.

Answer (score 2):

Using Feynman's Trick
\begin{align}I(p)&=\int _0^1x^p(x+1)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1(x^{p+1}+x^p)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\dfrac{x^{p+2}}{p+2}+\dfrac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}\Bigg|_0^1\\&=\dfrac1{p+2}+\dfrac1{p+1}\\I'(p)&=\int_0^1x^p(x+1)\ln x\,\mathrm dx\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dp}\left(\dfrac1{p+2}+\dfrac1{p+1}\right)\\&=-\dfrac1{(p+2)^2}-\dfrac1{(p+1)^2}\end{align}

$I'(p)$ is only valid iff $p>-1$

Comment: Why is $I'(p)$ only valid iff $p > -1$?

Comment: @Somatic if $p>-1$, then it is automatically greater than $-2$. This makes $I'(p)$ converge to a finite value.